# Is there a way to determine when I will have my 3rd attack with Guinsoo's?

Tags: league-of-legends

I was wondering if there is any indication, when I will be on my 3rd attack with guinsoo's rageblade to apply my on-hit effects twice(like a buff stack or a visual indicator).

So far the only option I saw was counting my attacks myself. But that seemed somewhat odd to me, as either it seems to reset after sometime or some targets (like towers or Sennas souls) don't count towards it.

So is there any indicator from guinsoo rageblade, telling me that my next auto attack will trigger its on-hit effect twice?

Answer (score 1):

#### Nope.

There is no visual indicator for when your next attack will trigger on-hit effects twice. The only visual effect provided is when Seething Strike (the phantom hit) activates. Below is a gif I took in practice tool to double-check this:

[image: Gif of visual effect when triggering Guinsoo's phantom hit]

You also do not gain a stacking buff, apply a debuff, or trigger any other less-visible effects when stacking up to your third attack. The only way of knowing when you'll trigger your on-hit effects twice is by counting your auto attacks, as you have, or by simply watching for the visual effect Seething Strike performs when it activates.

The attack count that counts upwards to 3, at which point Seething Strike activates, only remains active while in combat. If you exit combat (by dying, or by not dealing or taking damage from external sources for 5 seconds) after attacking twice, then your attack count is set back to 0, and you must enter combat and stack your attacks back up to 3 to trigger a Seething Strike again.

Comment: Does the counter reset at any point? Or can I even expect it to trigger, if I do my first and second hit, then die and still being on the 3rd attack with Seething Strike being triggered when comming back from spawn? If not so, what are the exact conditions it resets on?

Comment: @Zaibis I've updated my answer. TL;DR: You can only retain your attack count while in combat (with champions, minions, neutral monsters, etc). Exiting combat by any means (including death) will reset your progress towards a Seething Strike.